# When opening android studio I get "External file change sync may be slow" warning

Tags: android

[Warning when Starting android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mchuq.jpg)

First a command prompt window keeps popping up for ever then I get this warning.Any ideas on what causes that problem

[command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsyhA.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following line to either `/etc/sysctl.conf` file or a new *.conf file (e.g. idea.conf) under `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory:

   ```
   fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
   ```
2. Then run this command to apply the change:

   ```
   sudo sysctl -p --system [ sudo sysctl -p --system]
   ```

ref- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit

Answer (score 0):

What is your OS? If it's Linux, you need to grant permission for fsnotifier. 
This may help you: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/577484/android-studio-launch

Comment: No Iam using windows 7 and have allowed full control for all users for fsnotifier and still this problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This problems could happen on Linux OS.

To see the problem just open Android Studio from bash and take a look at the logs:

- [image]

You can also see the logs from Android Studio -> Help -> Show Log in Files

In my case the issue is glibc lib version.